# window xp network service don't start

Tags: windows-xp, windows-service

In a windows XP pc, joined to a domain, I have a service (SCardSvr) that use to run as "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService". Accidentally I changed the logon to local system account and the service didn't work properly.
So I'd like to set the logon back to "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService", and I did it leaving the password blank.
Too bad if I start the service (I'm a local admin) the service don't run and gives me this error:
error 5: access denied

I also set the service to run automatically and I restarted the pc, but nothing changes.
Any idea? I need the service to run under "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" credential...

Answer (score 1):

There is a complete Knowledge Base Article for that [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739213%28WS.10%29.aspx).

If it still persists after following the guideline, then bother Microsoft for a bad documentation.

Comment: And read the **Caution** section where it says: "Don't change the user!"

Comment: mmmm... so the the solution is, don't do any error first!?!?
I think they says that, if you change the user, the service could not start. I don't think they meant once you changed the user the service will never start again, even if you set the original user.